# Trouble running python in VS code python terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

even stuff like  help(int) seems to give me error in vs code terminal for python

help(int)
int : The term 'int' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:6
+ help(int)
+      ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (int:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Other examples:

from dateline import date
At line:1 char:1
+ from dateline import date
+ ~~~~
The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReservedKeywordNotAllowed

Although running this from the editor seems to be fine.

Comment: That's not a Python error message. It looks like you are running Python code in the interpreter of an other language (PowerShell?)

Comment: It's a terminal, not a python shell. In the terminal type: `python` and the python shell will start.

Comment: oh okay, why does the dropdown box say python then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're using the Python extension for VSCode.

As it is merely an interpreter that runs on PowerShell, you will still need to prepend your command with `python` for it to work, such as `python script.py`, shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Python VSC]